# discordjs fetch all channelsID from serverID

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to create a **js** function that takes discord serverId in parameter fetch and return array contains all channels Id in that server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this isn't a problem, I'll give you code and explain.

```
function getChannelIDs(fetch) 
{
  var array = [];
  let channels = client.guilds.channels;
  for (const channel of channels.values()) 
  {
    array.push(channel.id);
    console.log(channel.id);
  }

  return array;
}
```

First, it creates an array called `array`. After that, it gets the channels from the guild. Next, for every channel, it pushes it's ID to the array and logs it. Finally, it returns the array.

Comment: this worked for me                 let channels = client.channels.array();

Answer (score 2):

For discord.js v13 you could try the following.

```js
const discordServer = client.guilds.cache.get(DISCORD_SERVER_ID);
const channels = discordServer?.channels ? JSON.parse(
  JSON.stringify(discordServer.channels)
).guild.channels : [];
```

It will return you the list of channel ids.

Answer (score 0):

If you still interested in this for V12

```
        var array = [];
    function getChannelIDs(fetch) 
    {
    try{
    let channels = client.channels.cache.array();
    for (const channel of channels) 
    {
        array.push(channel.id);
        console.log(channel.id);
    }}catch(err){
        console.log('array error')
        message.channel.send('An error occoured while getting the channels.')
        console.log(err)
    }

    return array;
    }
    getChannelIDs()
```

This fixes the problem with not getting the array correctly

Comment: But that gets all the channels of the client not the channels of a specific guild as asked in the question