# Fetch all of the Discord threads on a server (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, multithreading, discord, discord.js

I'm starting out in Discord.js and trying to make a bot that prints all of the thread data from the server to the console. For all threads on the server, I basically want it to print just the name of the thread, the member who created the thread, and the timestamp it was made.

Previously [I was working on code for one](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discordjs/comments/wf8pgu/extract_thread_data_from_the_audit_log/) that prints thread entries from the audit log, but because that data deletes after 45 days, I'm looking to make a more efficient strategy to print all threads that have ever been made since the beginning of the server (or at least this year).

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947782/discordjs-fetch-all-channelsid-from-serverid) on fetching all channel ids for the server, and that code works for me, but when I try to convert that code to find data on threads, I'm struggling to figure out how to do that.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could approach this?

**EDIT 4:**

The code is now working to print some thread data, but I can't print more than 100 entries. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63322284/discord-js-get-an-array-of-all-messages-in-a-channel) that might help with pulling that data, but I need to convert it to threads rather than messages to use that.

With my code to print using cached data, it only prints 5-10, but if I pull from the audit log, I'm able to print up to 100. I still don't think that's the method I want though because it will delete after 45 days and I'd like to at least pull all data one time, then from there I can use this command to just pull less data after the initial pull if I do it more frequently.

Here's my current code:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js'); 
const client = new Client({ 
    intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, 
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
] 
});

client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log(`${client.user.tag}` + ' is online!');
  })

    // should be more specific with message, (so it can be like "!audit")
    client.on('messageCreate',  async function (message) {
        const fetchedLogs = await message.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
            limit: 100,
            type: 110, // THREAD_CREATE
            action_type: 110 // THREAD_CREATE
        });

        //const fetchedChannels = await message.guild.channels.fetch();
    
        // Checks which command was done; message.content gets the message that the user sent to trigger this:
        if(message.content === "!test"){
            // get the guild
            const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("694998889358557297");
            // filter all the channels
            const threads = guild.channels.cache.sort((a, b) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt).filter(x => x.isThread());
    
              // Title of the Thread
              const threadTitle = threads.map(info => `${info.name}`);
    
              // ID of the Thread Creator
              const threadUser = threads.map(info => `${info.ownerId}`);
    
              // Date the Thread was Created
              const threadDate = threads.map(info => `${info.createdAt}`);
    
              // ALL INFO, if you want an array just remove the ".join()"
              const threadInfo = threads.map(info => `Name: ${info.name}\nCreator: ${info.ownerId}\nCreated at: ${info.createdAt}\n`).join("");
              console.log(threadTitle);
              //console.log(threadUser);
              //console.log(threadDate);
              //console.log(threadInfo);
          } 
          else {
                console.log ("target doesn't exist");
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Threads are just channels that are parented to another channel, so you can fetch them all the same way as normal channels and then filter the result to only include threads.

```js
const threads = channels.cache.filter(x => x.isThread());
```

This will result in the threads variable being an array of threads for the guild.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification! That makes more sense. I've been trying to insert the code that you posted here but I'm having some trouble understanding where it would work into the code.

I initially added it inside the for loop, but was getting some errors, so I tried to work it into just printing without looping to see if I could just print one value starting out (you can see where I got to in my edited post above). Whenever I run my code, I receive this console error now though: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')`.

I appreciate you looking at this!

Comment: you need to run it inside an event, like the message or interactionCreate event, or you can pass through a guild to the getChannelIDs function

if you look [here](https://i.imgur.com/wWgRKl8.png), you can see how im doing it in my bot

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter through all the guild's channels and find the ones that are a thread.

```
// get the guild
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("guild ID");
// filter all the channels
const threads = guild.channels.cache.filter(x => x.isThread());
```

Then, you can map the information that you need:

```
// if you want an array just remove the ".join()"
const threadInfo = threads.map(info => `Name: ${info.name}\nCreator: ${info.ownerId}\nCreated at: ${info.createdAt}\n`).join("");
constole.log(threadInfo);
```

Comment: looks good but op wants to scope it to individual guilds rather than all channels in all guilds

Comment: Yeah you're correct. I've edited my answer accordingly. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Thank you for the replies! Unfortunately I'm now getting a `TypeError: x.isThread is not a function` whenever I try this code or the suggestion from the previous answer's code. I'm wondering if maybe I'm just missing a library or something? I updated my post to include my full bot code for both suggestions in the "EDIT 2" section for reference.

Comment: what's your discord.js version?

Comment: I'm working in v16.16.0

Comment: that's probably your node.js version. Look into package.json for `"discord.js": "Your version"`

Comment: Oh yeah you're right! So it turns out I was on an older version (v13) so I updated it to v14.1.2.

I'm now getting a new error that's preventing me from running the bot at all: `TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.`

Comment: Define your client in v14:

`const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });`

Comment: Thank you! That did it!

Though right now it only prints the threads from today. How would I print older threads? I added my code to the post under "EDIT 3" for reference with the v14 updates.

Comment: That is pretty weird. I have tested it and it prints out all the guild's threads, even if they're older that a day. Oldest one was 5 months.
Also, if you're trying to get threads that have been deleted, note that that isn't possible. Once a thread is deleted it's gone forever.

Comment: Hmm all of the threads are still there and not deleted on the server. It looks like they only go back a couple of days. It's very weird that the threads aren't even in order of when they were created. I see 2 from Thursday, 1 from Wednesday, and 5 from Friday (today).

I just added my bot to my server on Wednesday, so is seems like it might be possible that it can only see the threads that were created after it joined the server. Is there a way for it to access threads from before it joined by reading the message history or something?

Comment: You can filter threads by creation date by doing: ` const threads = guild.channels.cache.sort((a, b) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt).filter(x => x.isThread());`
And no, the bot can see all the threads even if they were created after joining the server. I doubt it but it may be a permission issue maybe?
There is no way to get a thread by reading message history, sorry.

Comment: The sorting code worked for the dates, thanks! I'm thinking that I may need to use one of the fetch commands to try and fetch earlier data that isn't showing up in there, but I'm not sure. The bot has admin privileges on my server and the bot's role is above all other roles, so it doesn't seem like it'd be permissions related...

Comment: So I decided to revert back to some of my older code on getting audit logs to see if I could find anything out and with that, I was able to access up to 100 previous threads, but no more than that, using fetch commands (since it will error if I up the limit to more than 100, I'm not sure how to break that limit). I'm assuming it would only go up to what's in the audit log as well. I updated the post with my old code that I got to print 100 threads in case that helps with trying to figure this out!

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot get the over 100 logs. This also wouldn't work because, as the docs mention, "All audit log entries are stored for 45 days.". Thus 45 days after the thread has been deleted, the information will forever be gone.

Comment: After working on this some more, I found out that the reason it was only showing a few threads was because it was only printing data from the open ones and wasn't taking into account the archived threads. I'm currently looking into a way to unarchive all threads on the server temporarily to fetch that data. This way I don't think it would be limited to the audit log at least.

Comment: Hi Eevee. I believe this comment section is getting too long to continue the conversation here. If you wish to keep discussing the issue some other place can you add me on Discord? My tag is: Crytek#5894

Answer (score 0):

Use **`thread.fetchActive()`** and **`thread.fetchArchived()`**; they will both return maps and you can edit your code from there.

discord.js **v14** https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ThreadManager?scrollTo=fetchActive